# Can we Create ASMX WebService in .net framework 4.5?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf, asmx

1. Can I create a new ASMX WebService in .net framework 4.5
2. I don't want to create a WCF service
3. Can I do framework upgrade from 2.0 to 4.5 with existing webservice

   I have got the requirement to convert my old asmx services from ,Net 1.1 to 4.5 version only but one more thing i have installed .net framework 4.5 so when i am changing one dll project from 2.0 and building in target framework to 4.5 version but still  sytem dll's are changing in 4.0 version only.Can you please tell me whether how can i see 4.5 version assemblies

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to create legacy web service.

Comment: he Wiktor thanks for replying but my question is can i create new webservice with .net Framework in 4.5 or not and can we do framework upgrade of my legacy asmx webservice from 2.0 to 4.5 or not any help will be appreciated or please give me ur id ...i will chat with you

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Okay. 3. Yes. There's really not much more to say.

Comment: I think the more important question you need to ask yourself is **why** do you want to use ASMX instead of WCF?

Comment: Hi Tim I have got the requirement to convert my old asmx services from ,Net 1.1 to 4.5 version only but one more thing i have installed .net framework 4.5 so when i am changing one dll project from 2.0 and building in target framework to 4.5 version but still i am changing sytem dll's in 4.0 version only.Can you please tell me whether how can i see 4.5 version assemblies

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can! PFB the Steps (I am using VS2013):

1. Create Empty ASP.NET Project
   [image]
2. Add Web Service(asmx) to your project
   [image]